# How to configure nginx reverse proxy to work during Oauth2 redirect?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, oauth-2.0, odoo

Disclaimer: I am a real beginner in networking in general and nginx in particular. I set it up for the first time a few days ago.

I have a set up a domain which redirects to a virtual server set up with nginx, on which runs a webapp. This webapp requires me to use SSO (Oauth2 with Google).
After authorizing the service through SSO, I get redirect to an URI starting with `http://localhost:8069/google_gmail/confirm?`
The webapp is odoo. I would like to know how to configure nginx or the webapp for a successful redirection after logging in with Oauth2.
Thanks!

Contents of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/odoo.conf`

```
    bart@odoo-droplet:/opt/odoo15/odoo/debian$
bart@odoo-droplet:/opt/odoo15/odoo/debian$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/odoo.conf
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                             /etc/nginx/conf.d/odoo.conf
# Odoo Upstreams
upstream odooserver {
server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

server {
server_name domain.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_error.log;

# Proxy settings
proxy_read_timeout 720s;
proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
proxy_send_timeout 720s;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

# Request for root domain
location / {
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
}

# Cache static files
location ~* /web/static/ {
proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
proxy_buffering on;
expires 864000;
proxy_pass http://127.0.01:8069;
}

# Gzip
gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
gzip on;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```